# symfony form type file not working

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a wierd problem. I can't add file type into form like so:

```
$builder->add('file', 'file', array('mapped' => 'false'));
```

It's throwing an error:

```
Could not load type "file"
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

Any thoughts what's causing that?

Comment: You miss a closing parenthesis — normal ?

Comment: just a typpo, it's there.

Comment: 2.7 - but I already found a solution, I had named a service like form.type.file and maybe it was taking other form or something else.. after renaming it, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate your form based on the entity class, please make sure that 'file' is exist as

```
protected $file;
```

in your entity class.

Comment: that's why I got there mapped => false, your solution is not neccessary and it's not solving anything I guess. I figured out there was some problem with naming the services, I renamed it and now it works.